# Laravel Populating fields with field name arrays

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

In my laravel form i have some fields that have a name like so:

> name="myfield[0]"

Im and using form::model binging in order to populate to fields of the form for editing purposes, which is working perfectly for all fields with normal names.

But for some reason the fields with the name arrays are being populated. I am providing the data that should be populating the fields as an array so the structure is the same e.g.

```
array myfields = (
    '0' => 'hello',
    '1' => 'world,
    '2' => '!'
)
```

> Form fields names
>
> name="myfields[0]"
>
> name="myfields[1]"
>
> name="myfields[2]"

In this example i would expect the array keys to match the and the data populate as such.

Its not, so have you guys got any ideas of how i get about this?

Cheers

Comment: IIRC, Laravel uses arrayed names in a Form::model() context as relationship attributes -- so for example if you had a model with $user->first_name = 'John' and $user->company->name = 'Ford', your form element names would be 'first_name' and 'company[name]' Are you added $myFields to your model?

Comment: Yes i am i can see all the data when i use a breakpoint on the form

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I can't figured a way to do that neither, what I ended up doing was this:

I get an array of the values, then I simply do a foreach in the view

```
@foreach ($array as $element)
   {{ Form::text('myfields[]', $element[]) }}
@endforeach
```

I know that this isn't the right solution or the correct one, but this solved the issue for me, I hope does for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 here. I'm finding the differences between 4 & 5 to be minor in specific areas. I hope this is useful

My array format is $object[x][attribute], $object[x][otherattribute]

I found this issue to be significant with edit forms with arrays and dynamic data.

```
    public function edit($object)
    {
       $object=  $object->toArray();
       return view('editView', compact( 'object'));
    }
```

My route sending the object

```
Route::bind('object', function($value, $route) {
   $thing = App\Object::where('variable','=',$value)->get();
   return $thing;  
});
```

Note, I could be passing it as an array instead of the controller. But until I completely test out its behavior (Good so far!), I want to be able to poke it with a stick.

How I open my form

```
   {!! Form::model(['object'=>$object], ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['thing.update,$owner->id], 'class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

An example text input:

```
{!! Form::text('object['.$idx.'][attribute]',null,array('class'=>'cloned_input form-control input-sm')) !!}
```

Notice that I'm able to keep the input value null, so it follows the order of

1. Session Data
2. Explicit
3. Model

At least I trust it will! So far it's working for my dynamic forms to remain on one template for each CRUD operation.